# Counting results of stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure returning ID, Name, Descriptions and takes no input parameters. However, I am interested in how many results do I get.

I expected something like this work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EXEC MyStoredProcedure
```

But I get the following error in SqlServer Managment Studio: 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'. 
Could you show me a little code example how can I do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This won't work. May I suggest:

```
exec MyStoredProcedure
select @@rowcount
```

Alternatively you could return the count as an output parameter

Comment: sorry my bad: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx. @@ROWCOUNT keeps working

Comment: The result of @@rowcount is mostly 1 in my case. I solved this by using using COUNT() against a OPENROWSET which executes the SP, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/40084013/54908.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Comment: worked for me; as SELECT @@rowcount EXEC storeproc

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the logic in the stored proc and return the count from the stored proc. You do this by using the @@ROWCOUNT variable immediately after your query.  This ihow it would work in MS SQL Servet at least.

**Stored Proc:**

```
CREATE PROC MyPROC
AS
DECLARE @MyCount int

...

SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ...

SELECT @MyCount = @@ROWCOUNT

...

return @MyCOunt
```

**Calling code:**

```
DECLARE @MyCount int

EXEC @MyCount = EXEC MyProc
```

Comment: ok this will work but then you can also use SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table. I think he still wants his data ... if not he should use COUNT ...

Answer (score -4):

Write a new stored procedure which does a count for you.

Comment: Definitely consider the other suggestions that answer the question and avoid this.