# Counting the number of rows returned by stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How do I count the number of rows a stored procedure would return the fastest way. Stored procedure returns rows around 100K to 1M records.

Comment: The fastest way would be to create a new procedure to perform the count, using something like @@ROWCOUNT after the procedure is executed will give you the rows that were returned, but if you are only interested in the count it is needless work to retrieve and render the output columns if you only want the count.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Select [`@@rowcount`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx):

```
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

After executing the stored procedure.

Comment: If I have more than one select quries then it will return the no of rows from the last statement.

Comment: This will not always work. For ex - It's not uncommon for stored procs to drop temporary tables as the last thing before exiting. In a case like that you would always get 0 in rowcount

Comment: @neesh thank you for explaining that.  I couldn't figure out why I was getting zero every time and that explains it. +1 to you.

Comment: If a select statement contains a condition in where clause inside EXISTS, which statement's row count will be returned?

Comment: What will happen if there is a pagination logic. It will return always the page size.

Answer (score 5):

You can define output variable:

```
create procedure x
    (@p1 int output)
as
    select @p1 = count(*) 
    from Table
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer is to use [`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is still valid, but I would not recommend to run in directly after `EXEC` like on [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14474517/5070879).

`SELECT` statement is not always the last statement is stored procedure or you could have multiple `SELECT` statements:

Scenario:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p
AS
BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE #t(i INT);
  INSERT INTO #t(i) VALUES (1),(2);
  SELECT i FROM #t;
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
END

EXEC p;
-- i
-- 1
-- 2

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
-- 0 instead of 2
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=562a2d29822d7ff87bc877fcb5b9ff6e)**

---

One way is to use output parameter(as many as stored procedure resultset):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p(@cnt INT OUT)
AS
BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE #t(i INT);
  INSERT INTO #t(i) VALUES (1),(2);
  SELECT i FROM #t;
  SET @cnt = @@ROWCOUNT;  -- immediately after SELECT
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
END

DECLARE @i INT;
EXEC p2 @cnt = @i OUT;
SELECT @i;
-- 2
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3daa2581b83d586c96ae4f2f04d2d038)**

---

EDIT: Using `RETURN ...`:

```
CREATE TABLE t(i INT);

CREATE PROCEDURE p2
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t(i) VALUES (1),(2);
  DECLARE @cnt INT = @@ROWCOUNT; 
   -- some other operations if needed
  RETURN @cnt;
END

DECLARE @cnt INT;
EXEC @cnt = p2;
SELECT @cnt AS cnt_rows_inserted;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/BM14KZMa)**

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio creates this code to run a stored procedure `EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[usp_Order_Add]    @ID =NULL,@VendorID = 21, @ProductID=12, @Quantity=7`" Do you how the value for Rowcount should be returned? Currently the last line in the SP after the Insert statement is this `RETURN @@ROWCOUNT` How should the result be returned other than using an `output parameter` or a `SELECT ...`?

Comment: @surfmuggle I am not sure what does the question "how the value for Rowcount should be returned" mean.  RETURN returns single integer value and it could be ROWCOUNT or directly or by helper variable: **https://dbfiddle.uk/BM14KZMa**

Comment: Thank you for the sample that is exactly what i was not certain about. 
There is no need to use an output parameter. Neither is there a need for a `SELECT @count_internal`. To return the `@@ROWCOUNT` one option is to pass the `@@ROWCOUNT`-Value to an internal variable `@count_internal` and Return this variable `RETURN @count_internal`. The caller receives the returned value see this fork of your example [dbfiddle.uk/_LrR4RR-](https://dbfiddle.uk/_LrR4RR-)

Comment: @surfmuggle Great to hear, I have extended the answer to also cover this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar task with a restriction that I must not alter the SP to get the count. Hence:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
reconfigure;
go

sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1;  
reconfigure;  
go

select count(*) from 
    openrowset('SQLOLEDB','Data Source=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;
    Integrated Security=SSPI','exec DBNAME..SPName')
```

Comment: potential restriction: "SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server."

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the same result

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NOMBRE_PROCEDIMIENTO
   as
BEGIN
   if EXISTS (SELECT * from NOMBRE_TABLA WHERE CONDITIONS HERE)
     BEGIN
       SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
     END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

So far the only thing that has worked for me is to:

a. Modify momentarily the stored procedure to dump the resulting dataset into a table. If changing the stored procedure is not an option replace Alter Procedure with Declare and remove the end, provide parameter values if not optional and execute as a query dumping the dataset into a table.

b. Script the table and drop it using SSMS.

c. Use the script to create a virtual table in the query and use Insert into with exec stored procedure to populate it.

d. Count the records.

Answer (score -1):

```
Create procedure procedurename
AS
Begin

    Select * from Table --if you want where condition write here

End

Exec Procedurename

Select @@rowcount
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Hatem, I think you might misunderstand what constitutes an answer. This is certainly an attempt at an answer - it might be incorrect (I haven't checked) but it certainly attempts to answer the question.

Comment: Placing a query as it is won't help, more explanation would be helpful.

Comment: @OGHaza: This answer is about filtering a query. Not about counting the rows of the (existing) query. These are two very separate things. Secondly, a code-only answer has severe quality issues. An explanation is warranted.

Comment: @Flater 1) NAA flag is not for low quality answers. This was 4 years ago, in the past 4 years the NAA flag has not been agreed with. 2) I agree that this is a god awful answer, it copies an answer from the previous year whilst introducing a spelling mistake (`Select @@roucount`). I was likely looking at this from a review queue where I didn't have that context though.

Comment: what if I have multiple select statements and i want rowcount for all

Answer (score -2):

/* prefix main result query execution follow with */

```sql
SELECT @mySProcRowcount = @@ROWCOUNT;
```

has been reliable with non-cloud based versions of MSSQLSERVER for many years.

not so much anymore with cloud-based of versions of MSSQLSERVER. i for one feel MS earned a 'for shame' comment for this in their rush to make all MS products cloud-based, first and foremost.  in their haste, they reveal their cloud-based tools are less ready for prime time than they think.

it isn't insurmountable; it's just more work for a quality ready-for-prime-time solution on your part.

Comment: Can you clarify your position on this, as without supporting data it reads like a rant?  The docs make no mention of it being unreliable in the cloud https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Probably blaming Microsoft for some error on their own part

Comment: This will only work if the last statement in the SP returns a valid count.  If you do anything - like drop a table, update another table, etc, the count will not represent the rows returned from the SP.