# How to perform custom pagination without knowing the total number of rows from DB

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, pagination, large-data-volumes

I'm trying to perform pagination. I'm using a stored procedure to get my data. If i do Count(*) on my tables it takes minutes to give me results as tables are big. How else can i do pagination without knowing total rows.

I tried to get the data for about the page size and tried to get the total number of rows from DB in an async call in the background so i can load the page quickly but get total rows to calculate the correct number of pages for later. It didn't really work. any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Using sql server, ASP.net, C#

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the total number of rows much faster:

```
DECLARE @TotalRows INT = 0;

SELECT @TotalRows =  max(ROWS)
from sysindexes
where id = object_id('YourTableName')
```

EDIT: @droiddev Possibly solution for row count of stored procedure results:

```
Create procedure procedurename
AS
Begin

    Select * from Table --if you want where condition write here

End

Exec Procedurename

Select @@rowcount
```

Taken from this StackOverflow post: [Counting the number of rows returned by stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474469/counting-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-stored-procedure)

I have not tested this to see if it's faster, but the question is essentially the same as yours.

Comment: Thanks, But i'm trying to get the total rows of the stored procedure which is a join of several tables. Any idea on how to get total rows quickly for this?

Comment: @droiddev I linked a similar StackOverflow post and a snippet from one of the suggested answers. I hope this helps, unfortunately I don't have a database that meets these criteria to test performance on.